# Getting date past a selected input in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a BI tool where I'm selecting the date and an integer input. I want to select or filter a table based on this selection. Like if I select a date in the BI tool and update an integer like 3, I want to get the date - interval '3 day' as date in my result and in BI tool I cannot do that.

So I thought of doing it in Postgres and like below i have tried,but no luck. Can anyone please let me know on this. How i can achieve it via Postgres.

```
WITH CTE_date AS
(
  SELECT {CALENDAR_ITEM_SELECTOR} as start_date ,{TEXT_INPUT} as subtract_integer
 )
SELECT start_date - subtract_integer  * INTERVAL '1 day' FROM  CTE_date 


Sample output
date : 2020-10-24
input : 3
Output : 2020-10-21
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? The date calculation query looks fine for me.

Comment: If `start_date` is a `date` value, no need for the `interval` part. `select date '2020-10-24' - 3` works directly

Comment: This is a wild guess, but does it help if you cast?  `select {CALENDAR_ITEM_SELECTOR}::date as start_date, {TEXT_INPUT}::int as subtract_integer`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That works for me! If you post it as an answer here please.